# how to write this pre commit hook

Tags: git, hook

when we coding sometimes we write debug code in our project,
so I want to write a hook to check whether there is debug code in changes.
for examples.

```
console.log('this is debug code');//DEBUG
```

let hook check the //DEBUG if there is //DEBUG in file the give a error say you have debug code in you file please remove it before commit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [grep with regex in pre-commit git hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589285/grep-with-regex-in-pre-commit-git-hook)

Answer (score 0):

The sample pre-commit hook is really close to what you want.  It is located in /.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample.  All you need to do is change the logic of the diff line.

`$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A -z $against` - modify that so that you dump the actual diffs (remove --name-only), and then pipe it to grep looking for both a + sign, as well as DEBUG.