# grep with regex in pre-commit git hook

Tags: regex, github, grep, pre-commit

I'm writing a little pre-commit hook to check for debug code this works well when using:

```
FORBIDDEN='console.log'
```

but when I change to:

```
FORBIDDEN='die(|console.log(|print_r('
```

it fails to catch anything.

FULL CODE:

```
FILES_PATTERN='(\..+)?$'
FORBIDDEN='die(|console.log(|print_r('

git diff --cached --name-only | \
    grep -E $FILES_PATTERN | \
    xargs grep -E --with-filename -n $FORBIDDEN | \
    grep -v '//';
```

Not sure if its regex or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping your parenthesis:

```
FORBIDDEN='die\(|console.log\(|print_r\('
```

Comment: then I get `grep: Unmatched ( or \(`

Comment: try double backslashes?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I don't use grep, but the parenthesis surely need escaping and that is the exact reason it isn't working. Your "unmatched" error actually happens if the parenthesis are not escaped, so I don't know what's going on but it is funky.

Comment: actually you were right but I didn't have `-E` turned on to make grep recognize it as a regular expression